# Como criar um arquivo .bat diretamente do C#?

Tags: c#, txt, bat

Estou fazendo um programa em C# e nele eu rodo um arquivo .bat

Olha como eu rodo o arquivo:

```
string batDir = string.Format(@"C:\Users\Desktop");
    proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "teste4.bat";
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    MessageBox.Show("Bat file executed !!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
}
```

Mas agora eu preciso **criar** um arquivo **.bat** diretamente do c#.
Queria poder escrever mesmo um comando no c# e assim criar um arquivo **.bat** armazenando esse comando.

Como posso fazer isso?
Sei que para criar um arquivo **.txt**
Usamos a função:

```
StreamWriter EscreverTXT = new StreamWriter(@"Disco:local\nomeTXT.log");
EscreverTXT.WriteLine(stringArmazenandoComando);
EscreverTXT.Close();
```

Agora, como fazer isso só que ao invés de TXT, escrever um BAT ?

Comment: Um `.bat` é um texto igual ao `.txt`, só que tem outra extensão.

Comment: valeu! consegui aqui

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tente dessa forma, você só precisa colocar a extensão `.bat` no arquivo, definir o local onde deseja cria-lo e inserir o código dentro dele:

```
int teste = 1;
StreamWriter EscreverTXT = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\file.bat");
EscreverTXT.WriteLine($@"Código bat aqui 
   {teste} teste feito aqui
   2 teste feito aqui");
EscreverTXT.Close();
```

Comment: mas quando eu escrevo o codigo todo que eu preciso ele corta em determinada opção
"echo off  " + textBox1.Text + " --column-statistics=0 -u" + nomeuser + " -p" + senha + " -h" + nomesever + " -P" + porta.Text + " " + comboBox1.Text + " > " + caminho + "bancotestado.sql"          

ele para no "nomeuser"

Comment: Dessa forma `int teste=1; EscreverTXT.WriteLine($@"Código bat aqui 
             {teste} teste feito aqui
             2 teste feito aqui");` utilizando o `@` você pode quebrar as linhas sem precisar ficar concatenando linha por linha, e o `$` para concatenar as variáveis utilizando as chaves, editei a resposta para melhor entendimento.